# Nodejs not sending a syn request to a server, error EHOSTUNREACH

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I've written a short program in nodejs that's supposed to POST data to a server. Unfortunately, this program fails. What's interesting, however, is that I've used wireshark to see what the requests are doing, and I'm not seeing as many TCP SYN packets as requests I've made.

The program is contained here.

```
//ServerTestv1.js

var request = require('request');
var grouper = require('./grouper'); //Placeholder program.

function sendSomething(obj){
  request.post(obj, function(error, response, body){
    if(response == undefined){ //This happens sometimes. I 'unno why.
      reject(error);
      console.log('Undefined POST Response, ' + error);
    } else if(response.statusCode != 201 ||  error){
      reject(error);
      console.log(error + response.statusCode + " " + response.body);
    } else if(response.statusCode == 201){
      resolve(body); //Resolves the returned object, with unqiue ID.
    }
  })
}

function inputParser(url, objArray){
  var pArray = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++){
    pArray.push(sendSomething(objArray[i]));
  }
  Promise.all(promArray).then(function(returnedValues){ //Handles the unique ID the server assigned to the object.
    var otherArray = [];
    for(var u = 0; u < returnedValues.length; u++){
      var relatedObj = {
        "value" : Math.random() * 10,
        "relatedTo" : returnedValues[i].identifier
      }
      otherArray.push(sendSomething(relatedObj));
    }
    Promise.all(otherArray).then(function(values){
      grouper.doSomething(values); //Placeholderfunction
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Not working how exactly? You are aware of the syntax errors ?

Comment: Ah, yes. The syntax errors aren't a problem, but in the actual program (as this is the problematic snippet of code), I get 'Error: ECONNHOSTUNREACH' and an 'undefined response'. Additionally, whenever there is an undefined response, Wireshark shows no 'Syn' TCP packet sent.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Node, more likely it's something in your network stack, like a firewall, that's causing the issues. Can you use a tool like cURL to make the POST requests?

Comment: Definitely. Also, when I send requests from node indiviually, they work just fine. But when I send a lot at once, it dies horribly.

Comment: >5 requests at once.

Comment: What Node version are you using?

Comment: @robertklep: Node v6.2.1

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this happen sometimes in Node with the DNS failing when there are a lot of concurrent request. The error is not typically an `ECONNHOSTUNREACH` error but it feels like this could be something related.

Does your `obj` array include the domain name of your API service? If it does, try using an IP instead of a domain name and see if the issue still exists. You can do this via something like:

```
require('dns').resolve4('domain.name', (err, addresses) => {
        ip = addresses[0];
    }
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't have time to try it right now, but, as the bounty is about to expire and be wasted, you can have it. :)

Answer (score -1):

might be you are flooding with requests, and therefore hitting timeouts for some of the requests.

https://www.sitepoint.com/making-http-requests-in-node-js/
might help.

Comment: It shouldn't be timing out without actually sending a packet first, I believe. My Wireshark capture showed no 'SYN' packet for the requests that were rejected with an error.